# Load Large Image to Fit ImageView

Tags: android, android-imageview, picasso

I want to load images of dimensions min-approx 1800px width and 1400px height into an imageview like in the layout below:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/customiseCheckBox"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:button="@drawable/custom_checkbox_bkg"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/customizeSelImg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/customiseCheckBox"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        tools:src="@drawable/artcard" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have tried different scale types but the loaded image does not cover the dimensions I have specified for the imageview and are loaded `rather too small`.

I have also tried using Picasso like below, I;m using a recyclerveiw of images:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final CustomizeViewHolder viewholder, int position) {
    final Customize customize = itemsList.get(position);
    viewholder.customiseCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            if (b){
                customize.setChecked(b);
            }
        }
    });

    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(customize.getIcon())
            .fit()
            .centerCrop()
            .into(viewholder.customizeSelImg);
}
```

but that does not seem to work. Is there any way I can display the full image into the specified dimens of the imageview without compression or quality loss? Thank you.

Example image I am trying to fit:
[image]

Comment: loading such big images will kill performance, i will suggest you having that same image shrinked like a thumbnail for the recyclerview items and then when you click them just launche the better quality one

Comment: Please explain more. I have tried increasing the imageview dimens but the image size still same. I want to increase the image to fit the values in imageview dimension

Comment: size and dimensions are two different things, you will not reduce image size just placing it inside an imageview, you will need to compress it or shrink the image resolution

Comment: can you post an image of your output with the image you are trying to fit ?

Comment: I have added the sample image. If I compress it online will that work to fit into the imageview?

Comment: did you tried fitxy ?

Comment: Yes, I tried all scale types but only centercrop came close to matching the imageview. Try once with the code and image. Thanks

Comment: do you have the url of the image itself ?

Comment: No but I can send it as drive link for you to test

Comment: @Andromeda -  you need tom find  image ration based on image weight X height then after you may set dynamically image height weight

Answer (score 0):

you need tom find image ratio based on device weight X height then after you may set dynamically image height weight.

```
public void setHeightWidthFromDeviceScreen() {
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
        int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

        //set banner height using ratio
        int bannerHeight = (int) (width / 1.8014705882);

       //set height to image
        imgSlider.getLayoutParams().height = bannerHeight;


    }
```

`1.8014705882`this is my image ratio based on   metrics.heightPixels  , metrics.widthPixels, you may change it as per your requirement

for find the ration of image

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
float ratio = ((float)metrics.heightPixels / (float)metrics.widthPixels
);
```